# Simple straight-line path algorithm

Tags: javascript, game-development

I need a simple pathfinding algorithmn to go from point A to point B.
A* seems like an overkill because It doesn't matter wheather I hit walls or not and there's no terrain. I was wondering if there was a simpler one which would find a direct path(a straight line) from point A to B.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You already know that what you want is a straight line. Are you asking how to calculate that? Are you unsure if there exists a straight line between any two points?

Comment: +1 this is a fair question. It's related to drawing a straight line on the screen in the old days, before we only ever did that through a graphics library.

Answer (score 5):

**Dijkstra's Algorithm**

You could apply the algorithm that A* is based on: [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) with the assumption that travel to each neighboring node is equal. This will still give you the shortest path (or paths as your network may vary) However you might still view this as overkill (since you make no mention of shortest path, only of linear)

**Implement Basic Pathfinding Yourself**

I suggest you check out the Artificial Intelligence Depot Beginner [tutorial for path finding](https://web.archive.org/web/20200204071343/http://ai-depot.com:80/Tutorial/PathFinding.html). It contains pseudocode for a very simplistic path finding algorithm and explains the basics in the logic required for understanding and implementing them. I have included the pseudocode below for your benefit:

```
 create a list P
 add the start node S, to P giving it one element
 Until first path of P ends with G, or P is empty
    extract the first path from P
    extend the path one step to all neighbors creating X new paths
    reject all paths with loops
    add each remaining new path to P
 If G found -> success. Else -> failure.
```

Please note that

> "This also assumes there is a tree or network from which contains the
> paths to be followed."

**A* - But simpler**

Other than that you can still use the A* algorithm and just make a very simple evaluator to determine heuristics for the best next step. In that case it would be very simple to use Euclidean distance (think absolute distance) to get your path. If you are interested, I've found that I learned a lot from [Patrick Lester's tutorial for beginners](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm) and from [Coke and Code's article on A*](https://www.cokeandcode.com/main/tutorials/path-finding/).

I hope this helps you implement what you are looking for.

Comment: The shortest path would be linear because I am ignoring all terrain.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to find a path through an array of terrain squares, or else a path through a connected set of nodes, then breadth-first or depth-first traversal work well. (One trick to limit the size of the traversal to do a breadth-first search, but start a traversal at both the start point and the end point, and stop at the first cell that both have reached.)

However, if you're just drawing a line from A to B on some grid, then basic line-drawing algorithms work. A classic one is [Bresenham's line algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm), which is pretty simple.

If you want a simpler version that just distributes steps on the X axis with steps on the Y axis, it looks like this. It's kind of like "division by adding". This is just the basics -- lots and lots of room for improvements! (python)

```
def line(x0, y0, x1, y1):

    # number of steps x and y
    mx = abs(x1 - x0)
    my = abs(y1 - y0)

    # the greater number of steps
    steps = max(mx, my)
    sx = 0
    sy = 0

    x = x0
    y = y0
    path = [(x0, y0)]

    while x != x1 or y != y1:
        sx += mx
        sy += my

        if sx >= steps:
            sx -= steps
            x += 1  # only one direction for now

        if sy >= steps:
            sy -= steps
            y += 1  # only one direction for now

        #print((sx, sy, mx, my))

        path.append((x,y))

    return path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(line(0, 0, 8, 8))
    print(line(0, 0, 4, 8))
    print(line(0, 0, 8, 4))
    print(line(0, 0, 0, 8))
    print(line(0, 0, 8, 0))
```

I used to tweak this algoritmn to create circular or elliptical arcs, oblique lines (i.e. one that come at the target at a slight angle), perpendicular paths, or even just running straight away from the target! I probably spent more time on this than I should have as a youth. ;)

...

One more thought; if you're programming a "chase" algorithm, where a robot chases some target, then there are a few fun variations on that. You don't have to calculate the full path.

- Move diagonally or along an axis: `x += 1 if x1 > x0`, `x -= 1 if x1 < x0`
- Move along 45 degree lines: `x += 1 if dx > dy / 2` etc.

Another fun one is to move the robot `x += dx / 10` ... while it's not taking constant steps, it makes for a pretty cool display if you have a bunch of randomly scattered bots chasing each other.

...

One more thought. This works when x and y are spacial dimensions (like in a grid or array), but also works if one of the dimensions is *time*. So, for example, if you want to distrubute 5 messages across 8 seconds, then you can treat y as time, and use the same loop to distribute some number of events across some time span.

Comment: I updated the code; it's a little easier to understand and tweak this way.

Answer (score 0):

Your question might be better placed on [gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/), but if you aren't worried about terrain and/or walls, then what you want is *not* a path-finding algorithm.  The difference between the two points (or vectors) is the "step" required to get from point A to point B *instantly*.  You therefore simply need to divide the difference, using some amount, to determine the "step", and apply that each frame.

Comment: otherwise there is a line drawing algorithm for if you need to move in a grid: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm